# Creating a Database in phpMyAdmin - not appearing in cPanel

Tags: mysql

When creating a database through an SQL statement in phpMyAdmin, it gets created alright, but it is not appearing in my list of Databases in my **cPanel**.

When I create the database through cPanel however, it all works. What if I want to restore a database and I want it to appear in the cPanel list?

What am I doing wrong? Thanks! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It's still server related - are questions about working with Windows or Linux interfaces also prohibited? Is it all about that CLI? I don't think we'll ever be able to avoid questions that involve *some* third party interface in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and I was able to overcome this by logging into WHM and using the tool called "Database Map Tool". It allows you to select the user account then tell it what database name you want to give the user access to.

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyadmin only shows the databases the logged in user has perms for. If you created a Db in cPanel as the site owner but are using a different user in phpMyadmin, That would explain it.

Comment: I am using my cpanel account for phpMyAdmin - but it wont let me log out - when I press Log Out, its like it refreshes the page. the thing is, I am creating the DB in phpMyadmin, and it appears in there at all times, however its not appearing in cPanel. And because DROP statements are disabled, I can delete the database..

Answer (score 0):

If a database isn't showing up in cPanel but it is in PHPMyAdmin you should run the following command:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/setupdbmap
```

This should correct it and make the database visible in cPanel.

Comment: Is that command runable from the System(); routine in PHP?

Comment: I need to be able to do it through PHP :)